# I'm trying to create an on_member_join welcome message that only welcomes members from my server since the bot is public

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    server = member.guild.id
    if server == 910015309824524288:
        await client.get_channel(910016013377077258).send(f'Welcome {member.name} to {server.name}! :partying_face: :partying_face: :partying_face: Make yourself comfortable')
```

Specifically welcoming a user that is only welcomed once they join my guild

Sorry I didnt mention this my first time using the platform.
Here's the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonnyadmin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jonnyadmin/Desktop/misaaland/misa.py", line 99, in on_member_join
    await client.get_channel(916932471986217021).send(f'Welcumm {member.name} to {server.name}! :partying_face: :partying_face: :partying_face: Make yourself comfortable')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Can you be specific about the problem with your code and include any errors? Do you have the members intent enabled in the developer portal and in your `client.intents`?

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonnyadmin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jonnyadmin/Desktop/misaaland/misa.py", line 99, in on_member_join
    await client.get_channel(916932471986217021).send(f'Welcumm {member.name} to {server.name}! :partying_face: :partying_face: :partying_face: Make yourself comfortable')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 0):

`server` is an `int`, not a `Guild`, since you stored the id of the guild in `server`. You're trying to access the `name` attribute of an `int`, which does not exist. The better way to approach this would be to store the actual `Guild` object in `server`, and then you can access whatever attributes you want later:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    server = member.guild
    if server.id == 910015309824524288:
        await client.get_channel(910016013377077258).send(f'Welcome {member.name} to {server.name}! :partying_face: :partying_face: :partying_face: Make yourself comfortable')
```

Here, we're able to access `server.id` and also `server.name` since `server` is now a `Guild`. You'd also be able to access any other attributes of `server` that you need.